# Error bound for stochastic gradient descent method

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, limits-and-convergence, nonlinear-optimization

To solve an optimization problem $\min_x G(x)$ using standard stochastic gradient descent method, we let $x_0$ be the initial point and $x_k$ be the $k$-th point such that
\begin{equation}
x_k = x_{k-1} - \alpha \partial G(x) |_{x=x_{k-1}}
\end{equation}
$\alpha$ is the learning rate.
Is there any good upper bound on the quantity:
$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_0|$ ?

It is well known that there is an upper bound on the squared sum:
$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_0|^2$, and we can use Cauchy inequality to get the bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_0|$. But is there any better bound than this ? Or is there any reference?